Error SetCurrentCellAddressCore function in datagridview when press Esc in VB.NET
I have error SetCurrentCellAddressCore function
after typing in column m_product in datagridview then I press Esc in keyboard.
Is there anything wrong with my code?
please guide me
Thanks
Public Class Form2
    Private list As BindingList(Of InvoicesDetailtest) = Nothing
    Private BindingSource1 As BindingSource = Nothing
    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        ' To reduce the flickering...
        DataGridView1.GetType().
    GetProperty("DoubleBuffered",
                BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic).
    SetValue(DataGridView1, True)
        updateDataSource()
        'Datagridview1.Focus()
    End Sub
    Private Sub updateDataSource()

        ' Our collection holding products
        list = New BindingList(Of InvoicesDetailtest)()
        ' Create our medium between grid and collection
        BindingSource1 = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = list}
        DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
        BindingSource1.AddNew()
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class InvoicesDetailtest


    Public Property m_product() As String

    Public Property Qty() As Integer
End Class

result error in file gif

result in diagnostic tool


When an error like this occurs, you don't just throw your hands up and ask others to do it all for you. You investigate, using the debugger. You then fix the issue if you can or provide us with all the relevant information you found while debugging, including EXACTLY where the exception was thrown. You've been told that you used an invalid value for rowIndex. It should be obvious that the first thing to do is find out what value was used and what the range of valid values is. If you don't know how to use the debugger in VS, learn that first.

@jmcilhinney , Thanks for reply , I've updated in the post of the results of  diagnostic tool

@jmcilhinney , since I didn't get a solution then I asked in this post . I've posted the results of the diagnostic tool so what should I do about the problem?

Unfortunately, all you've done is provide a picture of an error message we already have and a bunch of useless info. What you haven't done is told us where the exception is thrown and what the relevant data was in use at the time. You need to debug your code properly and provide the results. If you don't know how to do that, you should stop what you're doing and learn that first.

@jmcilhinney , the error is SetCurrentCellAddressCore function

@jmcilhinney , I got the solution and I've answered in the post

According to the below link I got a solution :
link!
So I added the BeginEdit event datagridview then the error is solved
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellBeginEdit
        Dim currencyManager As CurrencyManager = CType(BindingContext(BindingSource1.DataSource), CurrencyManager)
        currencyManager.SuspendBinding()
        ' Manipulate datasource
        currencyManager.ResumeBinding()

    End Sub


